# Apache rewrite rule not triggering

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to take this URL:

```
http://www.awesomehost.com/accountants/Ceribelli-Associates-cd01qazwsxoztfnlvsim.html
```

And redirect it to:

```
http://www.awesomehost.com/accountants/accountant-directory.php?ID=cd01qazwsxoztfnlvsim
```

And here's what I have in my .htaccess for the accountants directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^accountants/(.*)-cd0(.*).html /accountants/accountant-directory.php?ID=cd0$2 [L,P]
```

I have also tried it with a leading slash and the P flag removed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/accountants/(.*)-cd0(.*).html /accountants/accountant-directory.php?ID=cd0$2 [L]
```

But for some reason, its not being triggered?

When I put in some random text in the .htaccess file, I get apache errors so I know its reading the file...

Any help out there??

Comment: Where is the .htaccess file located? In the root directory or in the accountants directory?

Comment: Sorry, its in the accounts directory itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the "accountants/" part of the pattern. Apache only starts matching from the current directory of the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /accountants
RewriteRule ^(.*?)-cd0(.*?).html accountant-directory.php?ID=cd0$2 [L]
```

Comment: This is a dodgy as a sol'n, (i) You need to add a `RewriteBase /accountants`, then (ii) drop the **/accountants/** from the subs string, so it should be `accountant-directory.php?ID=cd0$2 [L]` and _no_ proxy as @Conrad suggests.

Comment: Updated. Please tell me if I messed up anything else.

Answer (score 1):

RewriteRule begins a match after the TLD, and you are matching start of line without a leading slash.  So what if you try:

```
RewriteRule ^/accountants/(.*)-cd0(.*).html ...
```

Btw, be careful using a programatically generated URL with a .* rewrite - watch out for greedy vs. non-greedy matching.

Also, be sure that [P] is what you want? You could run the risk of proxying to unintended servers if a maliciously crafted URL were used and your RewriteRule is inadequately filtered.

Comment: Hrmm, I've tried this and it's still not working. I don't know why this is becoming harder than it should be... Updated the main question with some info.

Comment: Yeah, didn't catch that this is in a per-directory .htaccess.  You will also need to strip the /accountants portion in that case.